# Maximize and Minimize Buttons disabled on my Quickly application

Tags: application-development, gtk, glade

I was editing some basic settings in my application window design in Quickly/ GTK when I noticed that when I ran my app there was only a close button, not a maximize or minimize button. I know this is probably a silly question, but I cannot find the setting to enable them any where. Please help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Only way I found to re-produce your problem, was to change the Type hint in the general tab - in the window properties . Try changing that back to Normal, if not already done.